# I was trying to build a API with node.js, express and mongodb. After installing nodemon mongodb went wrong

Tags: node.js, mongodb

It seems like the mongodb server connection went wrong but I was not able to figure out how to fix the problem. Can someone went through the same issue please help me out? Thank you so much!
Error messages in terminal are as follows:

```
(node:63820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/Harry/Documents/code/testAPI/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:503:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:127:13)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/Harry/Documents/code/testAPI/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:326:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:219:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:127:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/Harry/Documents/code/testAPI/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:245:50)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:219:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:127:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
(node:63820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:63820) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Could you update your question with the code you are using to connect or an example of how you are connecting?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's no database instance running at localhost:27017. Be sure to start mongodb instance before running your code.

Depending on your OS, the process of starting mongodb daemon very, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/